# Collection was modified in a foreach loop

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to get notifications from a bluetooth device sending records, and periodically update the UI to display the records.  The while loop below sits in its own thread to handle UI updates while the rest of the module takes care of other tasks.  `gattCallback` is an instance of a `BluetoothGattCallback` class that adds to a list of received records and returns that list when `getHistory()` is called.

My problem is that when I hit the `foreach` line, after so many iterations I get an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

As far as I can tell, `history` isn't being updated here or anywhere else in my code so I'm confused by the error.  I specifically retrieve a copy of the record history through `getHistory()` to avoid modifying it during the `foreach`. Can anyone suggest what might be causing it or any tips to find out?

It might be relevant that this has only caused issues since switching to a Moto E4 on Android 7.1.1 from a Moto G Play on Android 6.0.1.

```
        // Periodically check to see what needs updating
        while (!finishedDisplayThread)
        {
            // See if there are any new records to display
            int count;

            List<Record> history = gattCallback.getHistory();

            if (history == null)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count = history.Count;
            }

            // Only update the display if it has changed
            if(count != prevCount)
            {
                prevCount = count;
                List<string> recordList = new List<string>();
                if (history == null)
                {
                    recordList = new List<string>();
                    recordList.Add("No history.");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Record record in history)
                    {
                        recordList.Add(record.ToRow());
                    }
                }

                //Update the display
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, 
                                                           Resource.Layout.ListItemLayout, 
                                                           recordList);
                    recordCountText.Text = "" + count;
                });
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I specifically retrieve a copy of the record history through `getHistory()` to avoid modifying it during the foreach.

Are you certain that you're getting a *copy*? Imagine this implementation:

```
public List<Record> getHistory() {
    return history;
}
```

This will **not** return a copy of `history`, but a reference directly to `history` itself. If two different places call this method, any changes to one of the returned values will affect the other returned value.

If you want a copy, you have to do something like this:

```
public List<Record> getHistory() {
    return new ArrayList<>(history);
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh thank you that makes total sense.  If it had been my embedded end that's the first thing I would have thought of! It works a treat now :)